# Change directory to a SharePoint link

Tags: sharepoint, command-line, lnk

Via command line, can someone suggest ways to change directory (cd) to a SharePoint link (pointed via a xyz.lnk link)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map a network drive to a WebDAV folder and use that drive to copy files (or whatever you would like to do).

```
net use z: https://<url>
cd z:
dir
```

I would use PowerShell to parse out the url from the .lnk file (if that is neccessary).

Comment: @tako_tokyo, dont forget to mark the answer as correct if this helped you.